# Which is better JETTY COMET implementation or Resin COMET implementation

Tags: servlets, jetty, comet, resin, hessian

We've been using JETTY's suspended servlet implementation to roll our own COMET  web applications using JSON messages and XStream.

Does anyone have experience with Resin's implementation of COMET and how they compare?

Also more generically than COMET does anyone have suggestions on the best Java Suspended servlet 3.0 implementation.

Here are some resources:

- [COMETD](http://cometdproject.dojotoolkit.org/) - JETTY resource for the various COMETD implementations
- [Resin's Hessian streaming COMET implementation example](http://hessian.caucho.com/comet/)
- [JETTY COMET Suspend Servlet Performance](http://blogs.webtide.com/gregw/entry/comet_performance)

Comment: Not specifically Java related, since it's hosted, but if hosted works for you, try www.frozenmountain.com/websync. It has the best performance on the market (25k+ concurrent users, 20k+ messages/sec throughput).

Answer (score 2):

Both have pretty limited uptake in the community.  If you are looking for a decent & free Java based Comet solution I suggest you try something like the community edition of [this comet server](http://www.stream-hub.com/) or perhaps try implementing the [Atmosphere API](https://atmosphere.dev.java.net/) on top of Jetty.  That may not be the answer you are looking for but if you want an industrial strength Comet implementation you would be best off this way.  Just my 2 cents.